# Working batch file fails when started remotely through PsExec

Tags: psexec

I have a master copy of my software on a server.
I have 2 workstations that I copy that master server copy to, using batch files.
On each workstation there is a Backup_Software.bat file and a Backup_Software_Remote.bat file.
Backup_Software.bat on either workstation copies the server share which is mapped to X: on both workstations to the local drive D:, then it starts Backup_Software_Remote.bat on the other workstation which again copies X: to D: on that machine.
This way if I add software to the master X: I am one double-click away from getting the master X: copied to both workstation's D: drive.

Working directly on the PsExec destination machine, dir x:\software works correctly.

```
C:\>dir x:\software
 Volume in drive X is Puff_C~
 Volume Serial Number is B6A1-0D9E

 Directory of x:\software
03/04/2017  12:03 PM    <DIR>          .
06/20/2023  10:00 PM    <DIR>          ..
10/21/2021  08:32 PM    <DIR>          Unix
04/07/2019  04:36 PM    <DIR>          OS2
04/09/2023  05:03 AM    <DIR>          Windows
10/18/2023  11:54 AM    <DIR>          Linux
10/15/2016  10:11 AM    <DIR>          DOS
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               7 Dir(s)  24,102,284,435,456 bytes free
```

Working directly on the PsExec destination machine, robocopy x:\software d:\software /s /e works correctly.

```
C:\>robocopy x:\software d:\software /s /e

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Started : Mon Dec 04 22:37:09 2023
   Source : x:\software\
     Dest : d:\software\
    Files : *.*
  Options : *.* /S /E /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                           0    x:\software\
                           0    x:\software\DOS\
```

Starting PsExec on the PsExec source machine, the desired batch file can be seen to start correctly on the destination machine.

```
psexec64 \\puff -d -i 1 -u puff\user -p password -n 120 Backup_Software_Remote.bat
PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
Backup_Software_Remote.bat started on puff with process ID 8572.
```

But now the destination machine can't find X:\software.

```
C:\Windows\system32>ECHO OFF
 Log File : E:\Backup\Log\Puff_III\Backup-Software_Rem.log
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Started : Mon Dec 04 22:41:41 2023
2023/12/04 22:41:41 ERROR 3 (0x00000003) Getting File System Type of Source X:\Software\
The system cannot find the path specified.
   Source - X:\Software\
     Dest : D:\Software\
    Files : *.*
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2023/12/04 22:41:41 ERROR 3 (0x00000003) Accessing Source Directory X:\Software\
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

The Backup_Software_Remote.bat batch file works correctly in either a user or admin console but not if started remotely using PsExec.
I have no idea where to go with this or how to start troubleshooting this issue.
Thanks in advance for any help that my be provided.

All for now

I tried to run a batch file remotely with PsExec and I expected it to work as well as it does when running that same batch file locally.

Answer:
The remote batch file does:

```
Robocopy \\Plum\Software D:\Software /MIR /NP /LOG:"E:\Backup\Log\Puff_III\Backup-Software_Rem.log" /TEE
```

Which doesn't work when run remotely through PsExec, although it does work when run locally.

I changed the remote batch file to this:

```
Robocopy \\192.168.2.12\Software D:\Software /MIR /NP /LOG:"E:\Backup\Log\Puff_III\Backup-Software_Rem.log" /TEE
```

I changed \\Plum to \\192.168.2.12 and now it works when run remotely through PsExec.
Whodathunkit.

I wish I knew why \\Plum in a batch file works locally but not when run remotely through PsExec.

All for now